# Bye bye love - Where do I go from here?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I'm doing the **Bye Bye Love** quest in *Fallout: New Vegas*.

I've spoken to both Carlitos and Joanna, and have given messages to both. However, I didn't have a high enough speech skill to convince Joanna to escape from Gomorrah. I went back to Carlitos, whose dialogue options I have entirely gone through - they are all greyed out. Going back to Joanna only let me ask questions about her or exit dialogue.

My current objective is ***"Talk to Joanna, on Carlitos' behalf, at Gomorrah"***, but the only dialogue options for Joanna are *"Can I ask you some questions"* and *"Goodbye"*.

What do I do now?

---

**EDIT**:  The option to convince Joanna to escape from Gomorrah has re-appeared, but it requires a speech check of 40, not the reported 25.

Comment: could you please confirm if you are playing on PC or console?

Answer (score 1):

According to Gamepedia.com there's no way to complete the quest without the required speech skill:

> *•    It seems that there is no way to complete this quest without passing at least a 25 speech check.*

There's more [here](http://fallout.gamepedia.com/Bye_Bye_Love) but be aware this page is a walkthrough guide.

I found two ways to get around it but both involve cheating:

> Type the ~ key follow by: **GetQuestCompleted** (press enter) to complete the current quest or **Player.modav speech 70** (press enter) to add the required speech skill. You can always change it back after you finish the quest. To reset Bye Bye Love Quest type ***resetquest 110a63***

Comment: The problem isn't my speech skill - I would wait until I'd levelled up to put the required points into speech - but the fact that the 25 speech dialogue option no longer exists in Joanna's dialogue options.

Comment: I can't see a way to get it back without resetting the quest. It doesn't look to return even if you go away and get more speech skill. You can reset the whole quest. I have added the code to the end of the spoiler above.

Comment: well, i managed to get the speech option again but it turns out that I need 40 speech rather than 25

Comment: You won't get another chance to try a speech skill dialogue if you use it and don't have the levels. Always best to quit the dialogue screen until you do.

Answer (score 1):

According to the game pressure guide, **you require a 40 speech check, in order to convince Joanna to escape with you**. So that sounds accurate. Other users have reported 25. This could be due to a difference in version or platform. Since you have since confirmed a check of 40, I'll address the real problem in "what to do next":

### What to do If your Speech is too low

- **WAIT** : This is the most important requirement. If you try to pass a speech check you have not met, you will go down a different dialogue option, and fail the check. **[You will not be given a second try](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/959557-fallout-new-vegas/56840270)**.
- For this particular mission, **it is advisable that you hold off on the mission** "***How Little We Know***", **as progress** in the later **can** actually force you to **fail this mission**. You will not have any negative repercussions in the later mission from completing this mission first. In fact, if you have not discovered the later, you should, after completing this mission.
- **Improve your Speech**: Find a way to meet the speech requirements, and come back. There are lots of ways to do this, both permanent and temporary. Make sure any temporary methods are done just before you speak to Joanna. I have listed your options, below. For ease of use, I have listed the potential speech gains, first. I have also formatted them as bold, if the increase is permanent.

### Leveling-up + Progress

- **+15, +17**: *General level-up*: Each level-up, you receive enough distribution points to increase speech by 15, or 17, if you have the [Educated](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Educated) perk.
- **+15:** *Tag! Perk*: The Tag! perk lets you tag a fourth skill. If you do not already have speech as a tagged skill, this will increase speech by 15.
- **+5:** *Good Natured Perk:* The Good Natured perk gives you +5 to speech.
- **+5:** *Skilled Perk*: The Skilled perk gives you +5 to speech.
- +2, +3: *[Meat of Champions Perk](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Meat_of_Champions)*: If you have the [Cannibal](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Cannibal) perk, and you eat the bodies of Caesar, Mr House, The King, and President Kimball, you will gain a perk that increases both Luck and Charisma by 1, for 60 seconds after eating any human corpse.
- **+4** Complete the [Lonesome Road DLC](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lonesome_Road_(add-on)): If you have the DLC content, the Lonesome Road ends with bonus reward of 2 S.P.E.C.I.A.L. points, allowing for a potential +4 to speech.

### Skill Books

- **+12, +24**: *[Lying, Congressional Style](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lying,_Congressional_Style_(Fallout:_New_Vegas))*: This book gives you +3 to speech, or +4, if you have the [Comprehension](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Comprehension) perk.  [There are a total of 4 books in the main game, and 2 in the DLC](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lying,_Congressional_Style_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29). This gives you a potential of +12 to +24 speech. The [Old World Blues DLC](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Old_World_Blues_(add-on)) adds the [ability to craft them](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Lying,_Congressional_Style_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29), yourself.
- +10, +20: *[Meeting People](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Meeting_People)*: This book temporarily gives you +10 to speech, or +20, if you have the [Comprehension](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Comprehension) perk.

### Artificial Enhancement

- +4, +6: *Use Mentats*: [Regular Mentats](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mentats_%28Fallout:_New_Vegas%29) increase your Charisma by 1. [Party Time Mentats](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Party_Time_Mentats), by 5. The two stack together, giving a total of +6 to charisma.
- +2 *Drink Alcohol*: The wiki page on speech in Fallout: New Vegas reports that Absinthe, Beer, Irradiated Beer, Jake Juice, Scotch, Irradiated Scotch, Vodka, Whiskey, Irradiated Whiskey and Wine all count as an alcoholic +2 to charisma.
- **+1**: *Purchase the [Empathy Synthesizer](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Charisma_Implant)* for a permanent +1 to charisma.

### Equipment

- +2: [Sexy Sleepwear](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sexy_sleepwear_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)).
- +2: [T-51b Power Armor Helmet](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/T-51b_power_armor_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)).
- +5: [Daniel's Hat](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Daniel%27s_outfit) (requires [Honest Hearts DLC](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Honest_Hearts)).
- +2: [Sheriff's Duster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Sheriff%27s_duster).
- +2: [Bounty Hunter's Duster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Bounty_hunter_duster).
- +2: [Regulator's Duster](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Regulator_duster).
- +2: [Vault Jumpsuit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vault_jumpsuit_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)).
- +5: [Benny's Suit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Benny%27s_suit).
- +5: [Caesar's Armor](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Caesar%27s_armor).
- +5: [Dean's Tuxedo](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dean%27s_tuxedo).
- +5: [President Kimball's Suit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/President_Kimball%27s_suit).
- +5: [Pre-War Buisnesswear](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Pre-War_businesswear).
- +5: [Vera's Outfit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Vera%27s_outfit).
- +10, +11: [Naughty Nightwear](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Naughty_nightwear_(Fallout:_New_Vegas)).
- +10: [US Army General Outfit](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/US_Army_General_outfit).